# Effect of 30% voltage variation on life of tubular heat elements

Tags: voltage

In my country voltage variation can be up to 30%. Recently we had many commercial foodwarmers fail in the same locations while another brand of similiar equipment works perfectly.

The manufacturer of the failed equipment blames it on the voltage variation, but since the other brand works just fine, I have my doubts.

What can I do to determine actual cause of failure?

1. Defective heating elements?
2. Inappropiate heating element/thermostat combination?
3. Voltage variation? (if this is the cause, then why does it affect only one brand?)

Comment: A 30% overvoltage (1.3 times) is actually (up to) a 69% increase in power dissipation, based on \$V^2/R]\$ and the assumption that the heating element's resistance stays about the same at the higher voltage.  Why this might affect one brand is that the other brand's manufacturer used more durable components that could take the extra power dissipation. That's not necessarily intentional. The next batch of appliances from the "good" manufacturer could use worse parts. Appliances are a competitive business, so I don't imagine they will consistently spec heating elements for big overwattage.

Comment: It's a shame @Kaz didn't put this in as an answer, so the question doesn't come up in the weekly emails as "Can you answer this one?"